# Jplayer 'play' command after 'pause' with time

Tags: jplayer

Hello i am using jplayer for my solution. I load the media and on ready i use ('pause', time) command.
After that if i use a ('play') command my media starts playing from the beggining.
Is there something i do wrong as on jplayer's dev guide it is said on the play method: 
"Open media will play from where the play-head was when previously paused using jPlayer("pause", [time])."

Comment: why are you pausing the media in the ready event? Why have the media autostart at all?

Comment: This is the scenario that I need. Load the media but don't play it and move the play-head to a certain position. Then from an external 'play' command i want to start playing from that position. I don't want to load the media and use play with time command. This is the scenario I need and this is what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problem, when dealing with lost connection. jPlayer resumed playback from the beginning when a `.play()` method was called. So, at some point (in my case it was the error handler) I was executing `$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("play", event.jPlayer.status.currentTime);`. It gets current position and orders jPlayer to play from that exact position. Works flawlessly for me.

But, please, provide some code, maybe your problem is completely different.

Comment: I'm trying to play an mp3, pause it and then resume using jPlayer. I tried your example play method, and it did not work. I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined`. Can you please provide an example?